# What does this skull belong to?

Tags: species-identification, limnology

I was cleaning out my pool with a leaf scoop the other day and found a small object, which I assume to be a sort of skull or cartilaginous structure of something that had died.

I live in Sydney, Australia and in the pool there were a large quantity of water boatmen and dragonfly nymphs.

What does this skull belong to, and what is the purpose of the hollow, bulbous mounds next to the eye sockets?

---

[image: Skull front]

[image: Skull side]

[image: Skull back]

[image: Skull size (cm)]